# How should I punctuate a list of predicates which all have the same subject?

Tags: punctuation, writing, style

I'm writing a list for responsibilities of reviewers. All sentences in the list start with "Reviewers should/must/who/...".

Is there a punctuation rule that fits this situation and allows me to omit repeating "Reviewers ..."?

Comment: Have you considered a list of bullet points that follow the initial "Reviewers" and that each complete the sentences?

Comment: @Stephie: Yes, I have already written it like that but I wasn't sure if that was correct. Is it a common practice to do so?

Comment: Would be my first choice. Basically a checklist, right?

Comment: @Stephie Sort of... It is a list of things that reviewers should do to ensure that they are honoring their responsibilities toward authors, editors and readers. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can, as Stephie said, use a bullet point list:

> Reviewers must:
>
> - do this
> - do that
> - do this as well
> - do this last thing

This will also greatly improve the readability. It is a lot easier to pick out the different points a reviewer has to take into account than when they are put into a sentence. You can also enumerate the options in a sentence after introducing *"Reviewers must"* followed by a colon:

> Reviewers must: do this, do that, do this too, and do this.

Depending on how much space you want this to take in on your page or how important you think the difference in clarity and readability is in this case, you can make your choice between the list or the enumeration separated by comma's.

Comment: Colon needs to follow a grammatically complete sentence. I am confused as to whether "Reviewers must" is one. How about this: "Reviewers must do the following: ..."